# FLUTTER UI Config widget row with 2 dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-widget, dart-ui

I have problem with UI in flutter. Anyone have experienced in widget please help me.

**Firstly, here's the target from figma :**

[image]

both date and time is using dropdown.

**This is what it become after my code :**

[image]

**This is my code :**

```
Container(
   alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
   child: Text('Schedule',
       style: TextStyle(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 125, 150, 1),
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
))),
        
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
        Container(
            height: 40,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide * 0.5,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                onChanged: (value) {},
                  items: _dropdownDate.map((value) =>
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text(value),
                        value: value,
                      )).toList(),
                elevation: 4,
                dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month, size: 16),
                  hintText: 'Select Date',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        width: 0.8,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        width: 0.8,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  fillColor: Colors.white
              ),
            ),
        ),
        Container(
            height: 40,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide * 0.3,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
              onChanged: (value) {},
              items: _dropdownTime.map((value) =>
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(value),
                    value: value,
                  )).toList(),
              elevation: 4,
              dropdownColor: Colors.white,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined, size: 16),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        width: 0.8,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        width: 0.8,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  fillColor: Colors.white
              ),
            ),
        ),
   ],
),
```

**I want to make the size in the row like this :**

50% dropdown Date,
20% space,
30% dropdown Time

**and the problem are :**

1. I don't know how to configure it as a percentage of row space, not with MediaQuery.of(context).size.width because I already use margin.
2. How to made the percentage is auto fit no matter device the user will used.

Hope to solved this here, thank you before~

*Update*, after using layout builder :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) for that instead of `MediaQuery`. It's going to give you the available space inside the wrapped widget.

The code changes are below. This is the result:

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  // height: 40,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.5,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    items: _dropdownDate
                        .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(value),
                              value: value,
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    elevation: 4,
                    dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month, size: 16),
                        hintText: 'Select Date',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                              width: 0.8,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                              width: 0.8,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        fillColor: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  // height: 40,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    items: _dropdownTime
                        .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(value),
                              value: value,
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    elevation: 4,
                    dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined, size: 16),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                              width: 0.8,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                              width: 0.8,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        fillColor: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        ),
```

Comment: how to implement it in my code above? I've never used layout builder before

Comment: I've edited the answer with the needed code.

Comment: BTW, are you sure it's `20% space`? From Figma it looks way less.

Comment: thank you so much, I'll try the code.
in figma maybe it's only 10%, but as long I got how to do it will be configurable later

Comment: I already made an update, and you can see the update in my thread.
it just like have an error.

and by the way, do you have any advice for problem number 3?

Comment: Here you go: To fit the contents inside the `DropdownButtonFormField` just add the property `isExpanded: true` for each one of them.